# showing strange output while printing an array

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, matrix

The following program find out the sum of the left diagonal of the matrix. I faced a strange problem regrading the problem.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>

 int main()
{
     int arr[4][4];
     int i,j,l_sum=0;
     printf("\nENTER THE VALUE IN ARRAY:");
     for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
       {
          for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
          scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
      }
    printf("The matrix is :\n");
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
       {
            for(j=0;j<=3 ;j++)
            printf("% 4d",arr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
       }
       l_sum=0;
       for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
          {
                for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
                {
                    if ( i == j)
                    printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);//This line is problematic**
                    l_sum = l_sum + arr[i][j];
                 }
           }

       printf("SUM OF LEFT DIAGONAL IS :%d\t", l_sum);
       return 0;
  }
```

If I use the marked line I got wrong answer. But if I do not use this line I got correct result.

Output(correct- without the highlighted line):

The matrix is :

```
1   0   2   1
0   1   1   0
4   5   2   1
0   3   1   1
```

Sum of LEFT DIAGONAL IS: 5

Now if I use the specific line ("%d\t",arr[i][j]);

Sum of LEFT DIAGONAL IS: 23

For me this is really surprising.

If anyone guess the reason for this unusual behavior please share the reason with my post.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you tring to do here? `("%d\t",arr[i][j]);`

Comment: Try to display the value of the array elements where i=j .

Comment: Anyway it's best practice to use braces even for one lines (if, else, for, etc), that way you would not have bugs like this.

Comment: Yes you are right. I used braces and found the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without this expression statement

```
("%d\t",arr[i][j]);//This line is problematic**
```

you in fact have

```
if ( i == j)
{
    l_sum = l_sum + arr[i][j];
}
```

With the expression statement with the comma operator (that has no effect) you have

```
if ( i == j)
{
    ("%d\t",arr[i][j]);//This line is problematic**
}
l_sum = l_sum + arr[i][j];
```

So the sum is calculated unconditionally.

You could write initially

```
if ( i == j)
{
    ("%d\t",arr[i][j]);//This line is problematic**
    l_sum = l_sum + arr[i][j];
}
```

In this case the expression statement will not change the logic of the code because it and the following statement the both would be sub-statements of the if statement.

Pay attention to that these nested loops

```
      for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
      {
            for(j=0;j<=3;j++)
            {
                if ( i == j)
                { 
                    printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);//This line is problematic**
                    l_sum = l_sum + arr[i][j];
                }
             }
       }
```

can be substituted for one loop

```
      for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
      {
            printf("%d\t",arr[i][i]);//This line is problematic**
            l_sum = l_sum + arr[i][i];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re right the problem is this line  `("%d\t",arr[i][j]);`  With my current knowledge, I am not able to use explain this weird behavior. The code is correct in term of syntax but it messed with your program’s execution. You didn’t specify why you added the code in the first place. My guess is, if you just want to print `arr[i][j]` ,you can use `print(“%d\t”, arr[i][j]);`. However you can’t use `arr[i][j]` alone without printf() or other supported functions.